# How to save a java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime into a PostgreSQL's timestamp column?

Tags: java, postgresql, java-time

I'm trying to understand how to save a file's modification date I received as a `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime` into a column in PostgreSQL which is a `timestamp`.

Reading the PostgreSQL page relating to Java 8 dates & times: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html

I can just pinpoint this: *Note that ZonedDateTime, **Instant** and OffsetTime / TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ] are not supported.*

In the matching table (see link above) PostgreSQL advices `TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]   LocalDateTime` but some people discourage you to use this Java class, e.g. http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2018/03/14/dont-use-localdatetime/

And by the way, `FileTime` can only be converted into either a `long` (millisecongs) or an `Instant` (see Java doc).

So what am I supposed to do? I'm lost.

Comment: If I'm following `FileTime` is a epoch value. You should be able to use `to_timestamp(double precision)` to convert to a `timestamp`. See here [Date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) for more information. So something like: `select to_timestamp(1608228957.794995); 12/17/2020 10:15:57.794995 PST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> how to save a file's modification date I received as a `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime` into a column in PostgreSQL

Use the types `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `OffsetDateTime` in JDBC 4.2 or later to store the moment represented by a `FileTime` object.

```java
myPreparedStatement
.setObject( 
    … ,                    // Specify number of placeholder `?` in your SQL code.
    myFileTime             // Your `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime` object.
    .toInstant()           // Convert to a `java.time.Instant` object.
    .atOffset(             // JDBC 4.2 oddly does not require support for `Instant`, so simply convert to an `OffsetDateTime` object. Same moment, both in UTC, so no value added except to match JDBC spec.
        ZoneOffset.UTC     // We must specify *some* offset, so we might as well use an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` represents just that offset. 
    )                      // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object we can use with JDBC 4.2 compliant drivers. 
);
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

## A moment

> I can just pinpoint this: Note that ZonedDateTime, Instant and OffsetTime / TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ] are not supported.

That text is not a Postgres issue, it is a [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 issue. Let me explain.

The three classes `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` all represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Representing a moment requires the context of an offset-from-UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds from UTC) or a time zone (a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region).

- `Instant` is always in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
- `OffsetDateTime` is a date, a time-of-day, and an offset.
- `ZonedDateTime` is a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone.

Logically, all three of these map to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column in Postgres. Postgres takes any time zone or offset info to adjust into UTC, stores the UTC value, and then discards any provided zone/offset.

So you would think the JDBC spec would require support for all three. But inexplicably, the JDBC team chose to require support only for `OffsetDateTime`. That was an unfortunate decision as the other two types are more commonly used. At any rate, you can easily convert. Look to the `to…`, `from…`, `at…`, and `with…` methods.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Effectively the same thing as an `Instant`, a moment as seen in UTC. 
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

A particular [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) *may* support `Instant` and/or `ZonedDateTime` as well as `OffsetDateTime`. But use `OffsetDateTime` alone if your intention is to write portable code to be used with various drivers.

## Storing `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime`

### Column type

You said:

> 'm trying to understand how to save a file's modification date I received as a java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime into a column in PostgreSQL which is a timestamp.

Check the type of your database column.

- Your column **must be of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`**.
- The other type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` cannot represent a moment, so it *cannot* store the value of your `FileTime` object.

### Java type

As you mentioned, the [`java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html) class added a `toInstant` method in Java 8 and later. Just what we need to store this moment in the database via JDBC 4.2 or later.

Same kind of code as seen above:

```
Instant instant = myFileTime.toInstant() ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Effectively the same thing as an `Instant`, a moment as seen in UTC. 
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Or shorter, but not necessarily better:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myFileTime.toInstant().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

If you need an `Instant`, convert.

```java
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

You said:

> In the matching table (see link above) PostgreSQL advices TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]   LocalDateTime

Those two types, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE` and `LocalDateTime` purposely lack any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such they cannot represent a moment. So they cannot store your `FileTime` value as value is a specific point on the timeline.

### Adjusting into a time zone

If you want to see a moment through the wall-clock time of a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time & date.

```
Instant instant = myFileTime.toInstant() ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate text to represent that value. We can ask *java.time* to automatically localize such text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime​( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/5FRbzu). Note how the date and hour differ yet represent the same moment.

> instant.toString(): 2020-12-18T00:37:55.704644Z
>
> output: jeudi 17 décembre 2020 à 19 h 37 min 55 s heure normale de l’Est

## Date-time handling is tricky

You said:

> So what am I supposed to do? I'm lost.

Date-time handling is surprisingly confusing. Our intuitive understanding and quotidian habits are not helpful and actually are counter-productive as programmers doing this work.

The main concept to get *very* clear is: *A moment* versus *Not a moment*.

- The completion of a sale transaction, a record being created in the database, or a delivery being dropped at your front door — these are all moments.
- Saying that Christmas this year starts on December 25th, 2020 this year is *not* a moment, as the beginning of that day varies around the world coming earlier in the east and later in the west. Santa starts deliveries in the Pacific islands, and flies westward as the calendar flips to a new day successively hour-by-hour.
- Setting a dental appointment in six months that should start at 3 PM regardless of politicians changing that region’s offset-from-UTC — that is *not* a moment.

Another key concept is that programmers and sys-admins should think of UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) as the one true time. All time zones are but mere variations. While on the job, forget about your local parochial time; keep a clock on your desk set to UTC. Converting back and forth between parochial time and UTC will drive a person batty.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I can not use the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` because the table & database is beyond my control: I just have to save a "date" (?) whatever it is, Moment or not, I don't really care/understand what it is used for.

Comment: @maxxyme I’m sorry to hear you are caught working in a place where a broken database design cannot be fixed. That must be frustrating. As a hack, you could instantiate the `OffsetDateTime` object as described in my Answer. Then call `toLocalDateTime` to produce a `LocalDateTime` object. Doing so strips away the important offset/zone information needed to represent a moment. Then you would save the `LocalDateTime` object to your database column incorrectly typed as `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

Comment: @maxxyme You would then have to document the broken design, and just hope/pray that all other inputs to that column were adjusted to UTC before submitting to the database. When retrieving `LocalDateTime`, convert to an `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` in UTC with comments in your code explaining the hack where you are *assuming* the database value is in UTC but cannot really be sure because of the wrong column data type.

Comment: ah ah... you could't be more right about the situation!!! just to add I don't even need to read the data again! so I finally ended up doing this: `pst.setObject(i++, myFileTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toLocalDateTime());` because yeah, I'm French, and the guys who're gonna read the date are French too. I'm gonna validate your answer, because it's so complete and you've been be so kind with me! thank you so much.